# In the following remark, what is the symbol $Z$? "Elements of Mathematics Theory of Sets" by Nicolas Bourbaki. (English translation.)

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

I am reading "Elements of Mathematics Theory of Sets" by Nicolas Bourbaki. (English translation.)

In the following remark, what is the symbol $Z$?
I cannot understand what the author wants to say at all.

> Remark. When an abbreviating symbol $\Sigma$ is introduced, by means of a definition, to represent a certain assembly, the (usually tacit) convention is made of representing the assembly obtained by substituting an assembly $B$ for a letter $x$ in the original assembly, by the symbol obtained by the replacing the letter $x$ in $\Sigma$ by the assembly $B$ (or, more often, by an abbreviating symbol representing the assembly $B$).
> For example, having defined what assembly is represented by the symbol $E\otimes F$, where $E$ and $F$ are letters - an assembly which, incidentally, contains other letters besides $E$ and $F$ - the symbol $Z\otimes F$ can be used without further explanation.

[image]

By the way, I recently bought several books by Nicolas Bourbaki. (English translation.)
Sadly, these books seem to be beyond my understanding.
They seem to have been a complete waste of money.

I wanted to read "Algebra" and "General Topology".

[image]

Comment: It's another object akin to $E$.  The point the author is trying to make is that If they define some operation on objects with some known characteristics, that's enough to define the operation on *all* those objects.  If $Z$ is similar enough to $E$ then it is assumed that the definition involving $E$ applies to $Z$ as well.

Comment: Bourbaki's Set Theory try to be extremely precise, which makes it hard to read.  The "Remark" you mentioned just means that when we have defined what an expression (assembly) means THEN we can write expressions by just replacing "variable part" by other values, without having to present again the definition. It is a rather obvious thing, but Bourbaki wants to make it very precise. 

For instance, once we define that $E \otimes F$ means de tensor product of the spaces $E$ and $F$, then we can $Z \otimes F$ with no need to say again that the symbol represents tensor product.

Comment: I haven't read the book, but it looks like a $\mathbb Z$, not a regular Z, that normally denotes the set of integers.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity ,  At this point of the book, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not yet introduced.

Comment: My advice: don't read this book. Bourbaki has a bad reputation because of it, and it is indeed very painful to read, but the other books are much closer to ordinary maths books. More focused on rigor, but absolutely readable (and a lot of stuff can only be found there).

Comment: To be precise in the initial concepts is a difficult task, and this book bu Bourbaki solves it in several directions. Perhaps its complexity lies precisely in the attempt, without implying anything in advance, except for elementary psychological skills, to create mathematics as a science of formal records. You need to understand literally what is written and not make assumptions in advance, even, for example, for ellipsis. (continued)

Comment: (continuation) The answer to the question posed is that literally the old symbol is replaced by a new symbol and everything said for the old is transferred to new. As for the bad reputation and the advice to read or not, this is a separate topic that one could be happy to discuss in order to shed light on both bourbakitization and bourbakiphobia. Personally, my position is that for the desire to start accurate mathematical thinking from the very beginning, it is difficult to find such a strong book.